# Twilio Gather, how to resume the call in progress?

Tags: python, twilio

My twilio workflow goes like this:

```
# dial the number, include a whisper 
<Response>
  <Dial action="/calls/call-complete/">
    <Number url="/calls/whisper/">18325555555</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>


/calls/whisper
# press any key and connect the call otherwise hangup
<Response>
  <Gather action="/calls/gather-result/" method="POST" numDigits="1" 
  timeout="3">
    <Say voice="alice">You are receiving a call, press any key to 
    accept</Say>
  </Gather>
  <Hangup/>
</Response>

/calls/gather-result
# returns an empty response if no digits were entered
<Response/>

/calls/gather-result
# python code
 r = VoiceResponse()
 if 'Digits' in req and not req['Digits']:
    r.hangup
 return r
```

My thought was that the call will continue and connect after the calls/gather-result/ empty response, after you input any key, but instead both lines keep ringing never connecting.

How do you connect the call in progress after a gather prompt?

Comment: What do you return if the agent does press a digit?

Comment: Just the voiceresponse object like so:
    `r = VoiceResponse()
    if 'Digits' in post and empty...:
        r.hangup
    return r`

So an empty  <Response/>

Comment: Hmm. I'm pretty sure that should just work. Can you maybe try with a `<Say>` that says "connecting you to caller" (or anything really) and see if that changes things?

Comment: You're right it does work, the issue must have have been that I was using google hangouts from gmail to place the call. Then I tested the call by getting a friend to help using his phone. It worked. Not sure what the issue is with hangouts. Thanks for the help philnash!